# Adding Sizer to simple editor from wxPython tutorial quit right away

Tags: python, wxpython

The tutorial is here: [Simple Editor](http://wiki.wxpython.org/Getting%20Started#Validators) and its code is here: http://pastebin.com/x12f3DtN

My full code: http://pastebin.com/5sMDpC0X

I kind of modified the original tutorial by adding another menu to the menu bar, and added the ability to save file when we select `Exit` from the menu bar.

`python main.py -v` would show the widget really quickly, and then just went disappeared. 
Without the `Sizer` portion, I can run my app.

Where is causing this problem. There is no error. I can run the tutorial's full code without problem.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One evident mistake in the code lies here:

```
for i in range(0,6):
    self.buttons.append(wx.Button(self, -1, "Button &"+str(i)))
    self.sizer2.Add(self.button[i], 1, wx.EXPAND)
```

You have your buttons in `self.buttons` list, so you should add `self.buttons[i]` to the sizer.

Comment: Thank you. I got it. Why is that a problem? It was copied directly from tutorial, and tutorial's code work flawlessly. I don't quite understand what is done here.

Comment: In the tutorial (at least on pastebin) the third line of the code snippet given above reads `self.sizer2.Add(self.buttons[i], 1, wx.EXPAND)`. However, in your code `s` at the end of `self.buttons` somehow slipped and now it reads `self.sizer2.Add(self.button[i], 1, wx.EXPAND)` (note the absence of `s` ending). Change `button` to `buttons` and the code should work.